# Cant add function to create dynamic button inside renderItem FlatList

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to add a function to return button text based on the state inside the renderItem FlatList component.

```
renderButton() {
  return <Text>Button</Text>;
}

<TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    <TouchableOpacity>
        {this.renderButton()}
    </TouchableOpacity>
<TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

This code return an error

> function this.renderButton is not a function

Update:

```
<FlatList
      data={list}
      renderItem={this.renderRow}
    />

renderRow({item}) {
  return(
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        <TouchableOpacity>
            {this.renderButton()}
        </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  );
}

renderButton() {
  return <Text>Button</Text>;
}
```

Comment: Are you binding the renderButton function anywhere?

Comment: Need to see more code to be able to help

Comment: @Jayce444 not binding it anywhere else. only in this section of code.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I have updated my code.

Comment: You're not binding it anywhere in the code you've posted....are you binding it at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind the `renderRow` function to be able to access `this.renderButton` in it.

```
<FlatList
      data={list}
      renderItem={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
    />
```

or

```
<FlatList
      data={list}
      renderItem={() => this.renderRow()}
    />
```

or

```
renderRow = ({item}) => {
  return(
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        <TouchableOpacity>
            {this.renderButton()}
        </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  );
}
```

Comment: Got it working. Thank you. Understood to use of bind now.